# Trouble establishing WebSocket4Net connection with Xamarin.Forms Android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, websocket4net

We've recently reorganized our socket connections to have them use more shared code. I currently have the iOS project able to connect to the web socket and respond to events but I haven't been successful yet with the android project. It will try to connect and eventually hit the disconnect event with data stating "transport error". I'm wondering if anyone with more experience with sockets knows if there are any key differences between an iOS connection and an android connection? I'll post some of my code below and try to cut out the chunks I don't think are related. Thank you!!

This is my shared class

```
        public bool InitAndConnect()
        {

            //Create a socket
            sock = DependencyService.Get<IDabSocket>(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance);

            //Get the URL to use
            ContentConfig config = ContentConfig.Instance;
            string uri;
            if (GlobalResources.TestMode)
            {
                uri = config.app_settings.stage_journal_link;
            }
            else
            {
                uri = config.app_settings.prod_journal_link;
            }

            //Create list of events to monitor (basic connection events are already monitored)
            List<String> events = new List<String>();
            events.Add("room_error");
            events.Add("join_error");
            events.Add("auth_error");
            events.Add("update");

            //Register for notifications from the socket
            sock.DabSocketEvent += Sock_DabSocketEvent;

            //Init the socket
            sock.Init(uri, events);

            //Connect the socket
            sock.Connect();

            return true;
        }

        public bool JoinRoom(DateTime date)
        {
            //Joins a room for a specific date
            var room = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var token = AuthenticationAPI.CurrentToken;
            var data = new DabJournalObject(room, token);
            var json = JObject.FromObject(data);
            //Send data to the socket
            sock.Emit("join", json);
            //Store the date we're using
            currentDate = date;

            return true;
        }

        //IsConnected returns a bool indicating whether the socket is currently connected.
        //This is a bindable property
        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get
            {
                return sock == null ? false : sock.IsConnected;
            }
        }

        //Opposite of IsConnected used for binding reasons.
        public bool IsDisconnected
        {
            get
            {
                return sock == null ? true : !sock.IsConnected;
            }

        }

        private void Sock_DabSocketEvent(object sender, DabSocketEventHandler e)
        {
            //An event has been fired by the socket. Respond accordingly

            //Log the event to the debugger
            Debug.WriteLine($"{e.eventName} was fired with {e.data}");

            //Take action on the event
            switch (e.eventName.ToLower())
            {
                case "disconnected": //Socket disconnected
                    Sock_Disconnected(e.data);
                    break;
                case "connected": //Socket connected
                    Sock_Connected(e.data);
                    break;
                case "reconnecting": //Socket reconnecting
                    sock.Connect();
                    //do nothing for now
                    break;
                case "reconnected": //Socket reconnected
                    Sock_Connected(e.data);
                    break;
                case "room_error": //Error with a room
                    Sock_ErrorOccured(e.eventName, e.data);
                    break;
                case "join_error": //Error joining
                    Sock_ErrorOccured(e.eventName, e.data);
                    break;
                case "auth_error": //Error with authentication
                    Sock_ErrorOccured(e.eventName, e.data);
                    break;
                case "update": //update happened externally
                    Sock_ExternalUpdateOccured(e.eventName, e.data);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Sock_Disconnected(string data)
        {
            //The socket got disconnected.

            //Notify UI
            OnPropertyChanged("IsConnected");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisconnected");
        }

        private void Sock_Connected(object data)
        {
            //The socket has connected or reconnected. Take appropriate action

            //Notify UI
            OnPropertyChanged("IsConnected");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisconnected");
        }

        /* Events to handle Binding */
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

this is my android class

```
       public bool IsConnected
       {
           get
           {
               return isConnected;
           }
       }
       public void Connect(string token)
       {
           //Make sure the socket is initialized
           if (!isInitialized) throw new Exception("You must initialize the socket before using it");
           sock.Connect();
       }
       public void Init(string Uri, List<String> events)
       {
           //Initialize the socket
           try
           {
               sock = IO.Socket(Uri);
               isInitialized = true;
               //Set up standard events
               sock.On("connect", data => OnConnect(data));
               sock.On("disconnect", data => OnDisconnect(data));
               sock.On("reconnect", data => OnReconnect(data));
               sock.On("reconnecting", data => OnReconnecting(data));
               //Set up custom events requested by the caller
               foreach (string s in events)
               {
                   sock.On(s, data => OnEvent(s, data));
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               isInitialized = false;
               isConnected = false;
           }
       }
       private object OnEvent(string s, object data)
       {
           //A requested event has fired - notify the calling app so it can handle it.
           //Notify the listener
           DabSocketEvent?.Invoke(this, new DabSocketEventHandler(s, data.ToString()));
           return data;
       }
       private object OnConnect(object data)
       {
           //Socket has connected (1st time)
           isConnected = true;
           //Notify the listener
           DabSocketEvent?.Invoke(this, new DabSocketEventHandler("connected", data.ToString()));
           //Return
           return data;
       }
       private object OnDisconnect(object data)
       {
           //Socket has disconnected
           isConnected = false;
           //Notify the listener
           DabSocketEvent?.Invoke(this, new DabSocketEventHandler("disconnected", data.ToString()));
           //Return
           return data;
       }
       public void Disconnect()
       {
           if (IsConnected)
           {
               sock.Disconnect();
           }
       }
       public void Connect()
       {
           sock.Connect();
       }
       public void Emit(string Command, object Data)
       {
           sock.Emit(Command, Data);
       }
       public void Open()
       {
           sock.Open();
       }
```

My iOS class looks really similar to the droid class.. besides the Open().. Not sure what is hanging up on the android side.

Comment: Could you please post some error information when you established WebSocket4Net connection in android?

Comment: I'm running through the code now but I'm not really getting any errors, it just is not establishing a connection on the android side. Keeps on returning false. I initialize and attempt to connect the socket, and then attempt to join the room but I am not able to establish a connection to the socket so far.

Comment: In my ternary operator, for some reason with my iOS class it is returning sock.IsConnected appropriately but in the droid class above it is always returning sock.IsConnected == false. @JessieZhang

Comment: You can try to debug the request step by step ,then you can see the details about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SocketIoClientDotNet nuget package versions didn't match between my iOS and android projects. Once I updated my android package to match the version in the iOS project everything worked great.